# Find $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$ of the surface $g(s,t)=(s^2+2t,s+t,e^{st})$ near $g(1, 1) = (3, 2, e)$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, parametrization, implicit-function

> Consider the surface given by $g(s, t) = (s^2 + 2t, s + t, e^{st})$.
>
> Think of $y$ as a function of $x$ and $z$. Find $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial z}(3,e)$ near $g(1, 1) = (3, 2, e)$.

really tough question because i cant understand how it is related to implicit functions like what should be my $F(x,y,z)$.

thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If $(x,y,z)=(2s+2t,s+t,e^{st})$ then $y=\frac12x$ is independent of $z$,

Comment: my bad its s^2 i dont know how to write that in language really sorry

Comment: i have editied it

Comment: i tried but i always get one equation 2Fx + Fy + eFz = 0  where Fx means partial derivitive

Comment: anyone ? i really need help i am staring at the question for the 10th time i really need a hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $(x,y,z)=\big(s^2+2t,s+t,\exp(st)\big)$ implies
$$\text{d}x=2s\,\text{d}s+2\,\text{d}t\,,\tag{1}$$
$$\text{d}y=\text{d}s+\text{d}t\,,\tag{2}$$
and
$$\text{d}z=t\exp(st)\,\text{d}s+s\exp(st)\,\text{d}t\,.\tag{3}$$
Thus, the differentials at $(s,t)=(1,1)$ are
$$\text{d}x=2\,\text{d}s+2\,\text{d}t\,,$$
$$\text{d}y=\text{d}s+\text{d}t\,,$$
and
$$\text{d}z=\text{e}\,\text{d}s+\text{e}\,\text{d}t\,.$$
To compute $\dfrac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}z}(s=1,t=1)$, we require that $\text{d}x$ and $\text{d}z$ be linearly independent, which is not the case here.  Therefore, this suggests that $\dfrac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}z}(s=1,t=1)$ may not exist (see a comment below).

Here is a way to compute $\dfrac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}z}(s,t)$ for regular points $(s,t)$ (which you shall learn later that it means $s^2\neq t$).  Using (1) and (3), we obtain
$$\text{d}s=\frac{s\exp(st)\,\text{d}x-2\,\text{d}z}{2\,(s^2-t)\,\exp(st)}$$
and
$$\text{d}t=\frac{2s\,\text{d}z-t\exp(st)\,\text{d}x}{2\,(s^2-t)\,\exp(st)}\,.$$
By (2), we get
$$\text{d}y=\text{d}s+\text{d}t=\frac{s-t}{2\,(s^2-t)}\,\text{d}x+\frac{s-1}{(s^2-t)\,\exp(st)}\,\text{d}z\,.$$
Thus,
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}(s,t)=\frac{s-t}{2\,(s^2-t)}\text{ and }\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}(s,t)=\frac{s-1}{(s^2-t)\,\exp(st)}\,.$$
When $\sigma^2=\tau$, we see that
$$\lim_{(s,t)\to(\sigma,\tau)}\,\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}(s,t)\text{ and }\lim_{(s,t)\to(\sigma,\tau)}\,\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}(s,t)$$
do not exist.  Hence, $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}(s,t)$ and $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial z}(s,t)$ do not exist along the curve $s^2=t$.

As you can see from the surface plot below, the "ridge" of this surface is formed along the curve given by $s^2=t$.  The folding of the surface there means that $y$ cannot be expressed as a function of $x$ and $z$ near this curve.

[image]

Comment: I believe you have it backwards --- if the Jacobian matrix is nonsingular then $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$ can be computed this way and equal to blah, but even if the Jacobian matrix is singular it may still be possible to have $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$, trivial example: $x=s^3,z=t^3$ and $y=(st)^N$ for $N\geq 3$, at $s=t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the cross product $\frac{\partial g}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$ must be a normal vector to the surface.  On the other hand, if you view the surface as defining a function $y = f(x, z)$, then the curve $(x_0, f(x_0, t), t)$ lying along the surface must have tangent vector $(0, \frac{\partial y}{\partial z}, 1)$ which must therefore be perpendicular to this normal vector.

Comment: Except in this case, the cross product turns out to be 0 at that particular point - indicating that the surface parametrization is singular at $(s,t)=(1,1)$...  In particular, $g_s = g_t = (2,1,e)$, so no vector $(0, ?, 1)$ can be a linear combination - implying that even if $y$ can be expressed as a function of $x$ and $z$ in a neighborhood of $(3,2,e)$ (which is doubtful), that function can't possibly be differentiable at $(3,e)$.

Comment: I don't think $y$ can be expressed as a function of $x$ and $z$ near $(s,t)=(1,1)$ or $(x,z)=(3,\text{e})$.  After closer inspection, I found out that this is a branch point (or whichever technical phrase for this situation).  To solve for $y$, given $x$ and $z$, you need to solve a cubic polynomial equation.  The point $(x,z)=(3,\text{e})$ is where two roots of the cubic coincide.  To be precise, the values of $s$ there are $-2$ and $1$, where $1$ occurs with multiplicity $2$.